# Validação em operações Editar e Deletar por ID na url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

Eu testei pegando o id e passando via url, executa normalmente a operação, desde que o mesmo exista, caso contrário da erro como esperado.

EX:

http://localhost:55199/Pessoa/Delete/7

http://localhost:55199/Pessoa/Editar/7

Como eu posso tratar essa questão? Ver uma forma de validação, para que se o parâmetro id for passado via url direto não funcione ou algo assim, pois senão qualquer um pode passar qualquer id e deletar dados importantes ou editar.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Pessoa model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
            p.Salvar(model);

            return View("List", p.Listar());
        }
        else
            return View("Create", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        p.Deletar(id);

        return View("List", p.Listar());
    }
```

Comment: Não é alterando a URL que você aumentará a segurança da aplicação. Você não tem nenhum sistema de gerenciamento de usuários?

Comment: No momento ainda, estou estudando uma forma de criar ainda.

Comment: Isso que você quer, é alcançado através de authentication e authorization, pois a validação que você precisa é se o usuário está logado no sistema, e se o mesmo tem permissão para executar determinada ação. Fora isso, você não deveria fazer operações de exclusão via GET como mencionado na resposta do @ThiagoPires.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque você está trabalhando com o método GET.

O método **GET** :
*Com capacidade de 1024 caracteres, este método é utilizado quando se quer passar poucas ou pequenas informações para realizar uma pesquisa ou simplesmente passar uma informação para outra página através da URL, importante ressaltar que as informações passadas ficarão visíveis na URL o que torna esse método inviável para se trabalhar com informações sensíveis.*

Métodos **POST**: 
*Este método utiliza a URI (de Uniform Resource Identifier) para envio de informações ao servidor. A URI não é retornada ao cliente, o que torna o método mais seguro para se trabalhar com informações sensíveis, pois não expõe os dados enviados no navegador. Importante ressaltar que esse método não tem limite de capacidade para envio de informações. O POST utiliza uma conexão paralela para transitar os dados.*

Um exemplo para marcar uma ação como post

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Seu código --- Código
            return View();
        }
```

Na View você precisará fornecer alguma maneirar para que a Ação seja chamada, Link, Botão etc.

1-Observação: Quando você não força uma ação a ser acessada de determinada maneira, você poderá acessar ele tanto pela URL (GET), como por uma requisição POST.

2-Observação: O ideal é que você tenha algum controle de usuário, por exemplo como login para verificar se o usuário que está logado tem permissão para executar determinada ação.

Comment: Na prática eu tenho a aplicação que tem o link onde o usuário pode clicar no botão editar que o levará para a tela de edição, assim como para deletar.

O que eu não estou sabendo lidar é o seguinte, quando o usuário clica o sistema trás na url o link para ele como no exemplo que citei.
porém se por acaso a cara quiser sacanear o sistema ele pode colocar na url outro id na frente.
Queria saber uma forma de evitar ou validar isso.

Comment: Como citei acima, para evitar que um parâmetro seja enviado pela URL, você deveria forçar que o método fosse POST. A resposta acima não resolveria esse caso?

Answer (score 0):

Te aconselho a não perder tempo tentando fazer a segurança da sua aplicação tentando mudar a rota ou algo do tipo, pensando em uma segurança simplista, você pode usar o `Filter` do `ASP.NET`:

**Estrutura**

- **Controller Login**

  Aqui você pegará o usuario logado usando: `HttpContext.Session.Add("Nome", "NomeUsuarioLogado");` quando o usuário logar no sistema.
  **obs:** você terá que criar uma tabela de usuários.
- **Criação do `Filter`**

  Crie uma pasta chamada filter, e crie uma classe chamada LoginFilter:

  ```
  public class LoginFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
          object usuarioLogado = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Nome"];

          if (usuarioLogado == null)
          {
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                  new RouteValueDictionary(
                      new { action = "Index", controller = "Login" }));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Esta classe que será responsável por verificar se o usuário esta logado ou não.
- **Decorar as Classes**

  Agora basta ir ate os seus controllers e "decora-los":

  ```
  [LoginFiltro]
  public class PessoaController : Controller { }
  ```

  Você pode decorar método a método, mas nesse casa o ideal e decorar a classe inteira.

  Fazendo isto, apenas pessoas logadas no sistema irão excluir e editar os dados. Você pode estudar mais sobre o filter e criar novos filtros, separando o sistema por departamentos por exemplo. Você pode pensar em criar uma tabela de logs também, para saber quem excluiu algo.